# Do Massive Twin Quasar Jets Condense into separate Spiral Galaxies?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics

I was looking at a quasar, radio image of “Cygnus A”.

Do the massive twin quasar jets condense into two separate galaxies?

Do the average twin quasar jet emissions, plasma, condense, turn into nebula, turn into spiral arms, moment of inertia, like the Milky Way?

Concerning galaxy formation:

Can the average twin quasar jet emissions condense into two spirals? 
First, look at the quasar(s).
Second, look at galaxy-Sc
Third, look at galaxy-Sb
Forth, look at galaxy-Sa

The creation of the universe, computer simulations, do not entail: quasars were more common in the early universe; isolated galaxies, supernova, galaxies that have merged, and quasar jets that have disrupted galaxies etc.

Google “Cygnus A”

Search “http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy” Then go to Contents 4 “Types and morphology”.

Comment: The jet probably would not condense into a galaxy, but it would push against a hydrogen cloud, which could cause star formation.

Comment: The answer is no. The jets are just the radiation we observe from relativistic electrons.

Comment: Oops, you did it again ... please don't ...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_jet

I doubt if a jet can eventually settle down to a spiral galaxy.

1. It needs to get rid of it's velocity, otherwise it will spread out rather than clump together;
2. It needs to form atoms, which an electron ion jet cannot do;
3. It needs to accumulate extra matter, a lot of it (and it's moving very very fast so that's iffy); and
4. Apparently, if does manage the above three things, to stay a spiral over a long time, it may also  need a dark matter halo.

There are computer simulations of the early universe, programs designed for two main reasons:

1. To check our theoretical understanding of the experimental results of the cosmic microwave radiation; and
2. To try to understand the possible role of dark matter in the formation of the early universe.

Comment: I recently altered the document, cited sources, Thank You

Comment: Wikipedia Quasars - 2 Properties:
Quasars carry significant (but poorly understood) amounts of energy in the form of particles moving at relativistic speeds. A relativistic speed is a speed which is a significant proportion of the speed of light. Energy travel as electromagnetic waves typically on the order of 50% to 99% of the speed of light, while the electrons themselves move (drift) much more slowly.

How fast are the electrons moving out of the Quasar Jet?